# Get dictionary rank by value in js

Tags: javascript, sorting, dictionary, key-value

How do I generate a ranking for the value of kills in my dictionary?

I've tried everything about my poorly developed knowledge

```
for(let player in rank)
{
    dict.push({
        name: rank[player]["name"],
        rank: rank[player]["rank"],
            kills: rank[player]["kills"]
    });
}
```

**This gets:**

{'0': {name: 'Paul', rank: 2, kills: 12}}

{'1': {name: 'Mike', rank: 1, kills: 32}}

**And I want to get**

{'1': {name: 'Mike', rank: 1, kills: 32}}

{'0': {name: 'Paul', rank: 2, kills: 12}}  <- Order by kill or rank result

Comment: Could you give more information about what do you want to achieve? You have the `dict` array which should be sorted, right?

Comment: Could you also add an example of the rank object?

Comment: You're looking for the `array.sort` method

Answer (score 0):

Just use sort as following

```
let dict = [
    {name: 'Paul', rank: 2, kills: 12},
    {name: 'Mike', rank: 1, kills: 32}
];

let sortedByRankDict = dict.sort((a, b) => a.rank - b.rank);
```